# Remove html tags without attributes (php)

Tags: php, regex, recursion, tags

I have function

```
function remove_font_tags_without_attr($html)
{  
  $pattern = "/<font[\s]*?>(.*?)<\/font[\s]*>/im";    
  while(preg_match($pattern, $html)) {
    $html = preg_replace($pattern, "$1", $html);
  } 
  return $html;  
}
```

And html input

```
$html=
<p>
First: 0<font>1<font>2</font>3</font>4
Second: 0<font style="color:red">1<font>2</font>3</font>4
Third: 0<font>1<font style="color:green">2</font>3</font>4
Fourth: 0<font style="color:red">1<font style="color:green">2</font>3</font>4
</p>
```

A I need remove all font tags without attributes

My function above return

```
<p>
First: 01234
Second: 0<font style="color:red">123</font>4
Third: 01<font style="color:green">23</font>4
Fourth: 0<font style="color:red">1<font style="color:green">2</font>3</font>4
</p>
```

But problem is with third line Third, where correct return is

```
01<font style="color:green">2</font>34
```

Complete correct result:

```
<p>
First: 01234
Second: 0<font style="color:red">123</font>4
Third: 01<font style="color:green">2</font>34
Fourth: 0<font style="color:red">1<font style="color:green">2</font>3</font>4
</p>
```

Con you help me, please?

Comment: I try use [regexp.reference.recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php#95568), but that have problem with nonpair tags without ending slash.
`<br>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Disclaimer: *Don't use regex!*

It is not recommended to use regular expressions to parse HTML (or any other non-regular language). There are many pitfalls and ways for the solution to fail. That said, I do thoroughly enjoy using regular expressions to solve complex problems such as this one which involves nested structures. If someone else provides a working non-regex solution, I would recommend that you use that one instead of the following.

### A regex solution:

The following solution implements a recursive regular expression which is used in conjunction with the `preg_replace_callback()` function, (which calls itself recursively when the contents of a FONT element contains a nested FONT element). The regular expression matches the outermost FONT element (which may contain nested FONT elements). The callback function strips the start and end tags of only those FONT elements having no attributes. The FONT tags that do have attributes are preserved. I think you will find that this does a pretty good job:

### function remove_font_tags_without_attr($text)

```php
<?php // test.php Rev:20111219_1100
// Recursive regex matches an outermost FONT element and its contents.
$re = '% # Match outermost FONT element.
    <                     # Start of HTML start tag
    (                     # $1: FONT element start tag.
      font                # Tag name = FONT
      (                   # $2: FONT start tag attributes.
        (?:               # Group for zero or more attributes.
          \s+             # Required whitespace precedes attrib.
          [\w.\-:]+       # Attribute name.
          (?:             # Group for optional attribute value.
            \s*=\s*       # Name and value separated by =
            (?:           # Group for value alternatives.
              \'[^\']*\'  # Either single quoted,
            | "[^"]*"     # or double quoted,
            | [\w.\-:]+   # or unquoted value.
            )             # End group of value alternatives.
          )?              # Attribute value is optional.
        )*                # Zero or more attributes.
      )                   # End $2: FONT start tag attributes.
      \s*                 # Optional whitespace before closing >.
      >                   # End FONT element start tag.
    )                     # End $1: FONT element start tag.
    (                     # $3: FONT element contents.
      (?:                 # Group for zero or more content alts.
        (?R)              # Either a nested FONT element.
      |                   # or non-FONT tag stuff.
        [^<]*             # {normal*} Non-< start of tag stuff.
        (?:               # Begin "unrolling-the-loop".
          <               # {special} A "<", but only if it is
          (?:!/?font)     # NOT start of a <font or </font
          [^<]*           # more {normal*} Non-< start of tag.
        )*                # End {(special normal*)*} construct.
      )*                  # Zero or more content alternatives.
    )                     # End $3: FONT element contents.
    </font\s*>            # FONT element end tag.
    %xi';

// Remove matching start and end tags of FONT elements having no attributes.
function remove_font_tags_without_attr($text) {
    global $re;
    $text = preg_replace_callback($re,
            '_remove_font_tags_without_attr_cb', $text);
    $text = str_replace("<\0", '<', $text);
    return $text;
}
function _remove_font_tags_without_attr_cb($matches) {
    global $re;
    if (preg_match($re, $matches[3])) {
        $matches[3] = preg_replace_callback($re,
            '_remove_font_tags_without_attr_cb', $matches[3]);
    }
    if ($matches[2] == '') {    // If this FONT tag has no attributes,
        return $matches[3];     // Then strip both start and end tag.
    }
    // Hide the start and end tags by inserting a temporary null char.
    return "<\0". $matches[1] . $matches[3] . "<\0/font>";
}
$data = file_get_contents('testdata.html');
$output = remove_font_tags_without_attr($data);
file_put_contents('testdata_out.html', $output);
?>
```

### Example Input:

```html
<font attrib="value">
    <font>
        <font attrib="value">
            <font>
                <font attrib="value">
                </font>
            </font>
        </font>
    </font>
</font>
```

### Example Output:

```html
<font attrib="value">

        <font attrib="value">

                <font attrib="value">
                </font>

        </font>

</font>
```

The complexity of the regex is required to properly handle tag attributes having values that may contain `<>` angle brackets.

Comment: +1 for solid work, but I suspect this would be easier to maintain if you used a proper xml parser instead, like http://us.php.net/dom

Comment: Yes, but when using the DOM, there may be default attributes assigned to an element even when no attributes were specified in the markup - for example: `elem.class==""` (I've seen this happen when using DOM with JavaScript.) But I definitely _DO_ agree that, for any production code, a proper HTML parser is to be preferred over using regex.

Answer (score 1):

Make it greedy:

```
$pattern = "/<font[\s]*?>(.*)<\/font[\s]*>/im";
```

Greedy:
* (star)    Repeats the previous item zero or more times. Greedy, so as many items as possible will be matched before trying permutations with less matches of the preceding item, up to the point where the preceding item is not matched at all.

Comment: Have to say, this might work, but is not the proper way to do this, there are ways to match nested tags with regex, but thats too complex to explain for me. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: Than it's return incorrent second line 

     `Second: 0<font style="color:red">12</font>34`

Correct:

     `Second: 0<font style="color:red">123</font>4`

Comment: @user1102223: If you want to match tags according to nesting, then you need a `(?R)` recursive regex. Please research and solve that *yourself*. Because html libraries already can deal with nested html, it's not relevant to anyone to solve your one regex issue. Too much effort.

Comment: @mario - Unless there is someone (with evidently way too much time on their hands), who actually _enjoys_ solving tough regex problems for free. Guilty as charged!

Answer (score 0):

If php can't do this then it can't. I'm going to try to do it and will post back the php code if it can. The Perl code is just a template of how I'm trying it.

**Edit**
Perl code removed, PHP code added. Ideone test case is here http://www.ideone.com/9b2Ap

Expanded regex -

```
  $regex = "~
     $comment
   | (                     #1                            
       (?:                                             
           $open                                       
         | ($openatt)        #2                          
       )                                               
       (                     #3                       
          (?:  $comment                                         
             | (?> (?:(?!$openclose|$comment) . )+ ) 
             | (?1)                                         
          )*                                               
       )                                                   
       ($close)              #4                              
     )                                                 
  ~xs";
```

php -

```
<?php

//##
  $html = '
      <font>
      <p>
        First: _0<font>_1<font>_2</font>_3</font>_4
        Second: _5<font style="color:red">_6<font>_7</font>_8</font>_9
        Third: _10<font>_11<font style="color:green">_12</font>_13</font>_14
        Fourth: _15<font style="color:red">_16<font style="color:green">_17</font>_18</font>_19
      </p>
      </font>
   ';

//##
  $comment   = '<!--.*?-->';
  $open      = '<font\s*>';
  $openatt   = '<font \s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+ (?<!/)>';
  $close     = '</font\s*>';
  $openclose = '</?font (?:\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+)? (?<!/)>';

  $regex = "~
     $comment
   | (                             #1
       (?: $open | ($openatt) )                                       #2
       ( (?:$comment | (?>(?:(?!$openclose|$comment).)+) | (?1))* )   #3
       ($close)                                                       #4
     )
  ~xs";


//##
  print "Before:\n$html\n\n";
  $html = remove_font_tags_without_attr( $html );
  print "After:\n$html\n";
  exit;

//##
 function
   remove_font_tags_without_attr( $html_seg )
   {
     global $regex;
     return  preg_replace_callback( $regex, 'check_attr_cb', $html_seg );
   }

 function
   check_attr_cb( $matches )
   {
     if ($matches[1] == '')
        return $matches[0];
     $begin = $matches[2];
     $core  = $matches[3];
     $end   = $matches[4];

     if ($begin == '')
        $end = '';
     return  $begin . (remove_font_tags_without_attr( $core )) . $end;
   }
?>
```